# "Expected type parameter, found integer" when called from a function but not when called from main

Tags: generics, rust

```
struct Cache<T> {
    key: String,
    val: T
}

impl<T> Cache<T> {
    fn new(k: String, v: T) -> Cache<T> {
        Cache { key: k, val: v }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, v: T) {
        self.val = v;
    }
}

fn increment<T>(cache: &mut Cache<T>, v: T) {
    cache.update(v);
}

fn main() {
    let mut c = Cache::new("akshay".to_string(), 21);
    c.update(25);
    println!("c = {}", c.val);
    increment(&mut c, 30);
    println!("c = {}", c.val);
}
```

This example works fine. But if I change `cache.update(v);` to `cache.update(25);` in the `increment` function, I get the following error:

```
cache.update(25);
|            ^^ expected type parameter, found integer
|
= note: expected type `T`
          found type `{integer}`
= help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
```

So, my question is why does the `cache.update(25)` method work from the `main` function but not from the `increment` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in `main`, the compiler knows that it's dealing with a `Cache` with an integer type as the type parameter. However, in the `increment` function, one could pass in a `Cache` of any generic type since you are accepting a `Cache<T>` as a parameter. Thus, if you still tried to call `update` with an integer argument on a `Cache<T>`, it would be an issue and therefore the compiler doesn't allow it. Take for example if `increment` was called with a `Cache<String>` as an argument, how would `cache.update(25)` work?

If you wish to only work with `Cache<i32>` for example, you can restrict your `increment` function's parameter type:

```
fn increment(cache: &mut Cache<i32>, v: i32)
```

otherwise in the generic version of the function, you will have to use just values of type `T` and cannot do things like `cache.update(25)`

Comment: I want to keep `increment` generic because I'll be getting the value for `v` from a TCP connection. So it could be any type. So the increment function will look more like `let s = ...(getting value from the socket)` and then `cache.update(s)`. But this gives the compiler error

Comment: Oh I see whats happening. Sorry, I'm still in the mental model of python and ruby :)